# How to find path using BFS in corners search of Pacman search project

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search, pacman

I am trying to solve [this](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/pacman/html/navigation.html?page=p1/p1_q5) problem of the Berkley Pacman Search Project. The question states that I need to solve [bfs](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/pacman/html/navigation.html?page=p1/p1_q2) problem first, and then only change the representation of goal state to solve the corners problem. 
[Here](https://dpaste.de/kxu5) is my code of bfs which returns the smallest path from root to a state.

Now issue with my [isGoalState function](https://dpaste.de/tZoR) is , that when all the four corners are visited it tells the goalstate is achieved, but the bfs function realizes that that goal state is only the last corner position. Hence gives me a path from the starting position of Pacman to the last corner, and not the path covering all the corners

Can u tell how should I modify my bfs function, and goal state function to accommodate this. I tried looking at the solutions on net, but couldn't find one that is correct.

Also I think the solution to this problem should be a generalized bfs with a goal state function provided, that should work in normal cases too.

Comment: Did you try to build a new graph, say with "layers" that would basically be copies of the original graph and reaching a corner would allow you (edges between the layers) to go from one layer to another so that the goal state(s) would be in a high layer?

Comment: Your question is a bit too dependent on links at the moment. Ideally a question should not be dependent on *any* links - all relevant information (i.e. the problem statement and code) should be included in the question itself, although you're welcome to still include the links as *additional* reference. You're also welcome to, instead of the actual code, put pseudo-code or a high-level description in the question if you feel the code is too long, assuming that would useful, considering that one often needs actual code to suggest changes.

Comment: @Anubhav I am stuck on it as well, did you happen to find a solution. I know it's been a long time but still :P

Comment: @alDiablo You can see the solution at https://github.com/anubhav914/pacman

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution in BFS function depends on the function named `getPath()` which does not exist!

Comment: Did you solve it? If yes can you give me some hints about how you approach the problems? I don't want to look into the solution directly.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus Yes I am doing it alone. why? Also how do you know about 580 assignment?

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus Can you email me on ssolunke@gmu.edu? Let's talk there in detail!